# Regex lookbehind alternative for Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, safari

I have implemented this regex for matching a string for validation purposes:
`^(?<serialCode>[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3})(?:(?<serialMarket>[a-zA-Z]{1,2})(?<serialSuffix>(?<=^.{5})[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?)?`

I'm using it in JS using `match()` function like this:

```js
const regex = '^(?<serialCode>[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3})(?:(?<serialMarket>[a-zA-Z]{1,2})(?<serialSuffix>(?<=^.{5})[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?)?';
const stringToMatch = 'EV1FOO12FF344';
const result = stringToMatch.match(new RegExp(regex));
console.log(result); // returns each group for match and also the full match
```

What basically this does is that it's doing the following step by step validations and creating groups:

- first 3 characters should be only alphanumeric characters
- characters 4 and 5 should be only letters
- all the rest of the characters should be alphanumeric characters

This validation is done for every typed value in an input field, **character by character**.

Using lookbehind as you can see above, this works perfectly for my purposes in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers.

**The problem**: `lookbehind`(in current case `(?<=^.{5})`) is not supported on Safari browser as per this link: https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind We receive this error in this case: `Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`

Is there any alternative to that lookbehind so the regex will work in the exact same way?

I have the link where I tested some values for exemplification: https://regex101.com/r/fPmiTk/1
There you can see how the strings are matched and how the groups are created.

Comment: So `serialMarket` is not required? And `serialSuffix` can only exist if both `serialCode` and `serialMarket` exist?

Comment: Every group should be created if at least one character is matched in order. If no match at all, then the group should not be created for that specific match. So the group should exist only if there is at least a match from beginning of the group, character by character validation. You can check in the link here https://regex101.com/r/fPmiTk/1 This is the working example, the issue is that this is implemented using `lookbehind` which gives an error in Safari.

Comment: I see. I'll have to check it out more after my meeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is a way with a single regex with no lookbehind or conditionals support thus I suggest the following approach combining regex and additional programming logic:

```js
var texts = ['abcfobar','abc33bar'];
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3})(?:([a-zA-Z]{1,2})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)?/;
for (var i=0; i<texts.length;i++) {
  var serialCode = '';
  var serialMarket = '';
  var serialSuffixmatch = ''; 
  var match = texts[i].match(regex);
  if (match) {
    serialCode = match[1];
    serialMarket = (match[2] || "");
    if (serialCode.length == 3 && serialMarket.length == 2) {
      serialSuffixmatch = match[3];
    }
  }
  console.log(texts[i], '=>', serialCode + "\n" + serialMarket + "\n" + serialSuffixmatch);
}
```

That is, simply use numbered capturing groups, and once a match is obtained, check the length of the first and second groups, and if the sum of their lengths is 5, grab Group 3 value, too.

Comment: This seems to work for my purpose. Thank you so much! Too bad `lookbehind` is still not supported in all the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional to start with your most restrictive pattern and work your way backwards to the least restrictive one:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3})
```

I don't know if the named capture groups have any significance for your JS code logic but unfortunately you cannot declare the same capture group name.

https://regex101.com/r/2uztK5/1